# What is the equation of this graph?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This will sound very dumb, but I want $1000$ coordinates of this shape:

[image: MyImage]

How can I do that?

Comment: Assuming that the peaks and the valleys are supposed to be the same shape (you had to handdraw the valleys?) it looks like a transformed $\operatorname{sine}$ curve. If you want the valleys to actually be broader than the peaks, this question is a bit harder to answer. Maybe your curve could be given by an equation like $y = 500\cos(\frac{500x}{6\pi})\;$?

Comment: Oops, should be $-500\cos(\frac{6\pi}{500}x)$. Sorry.

Comment: @MikePierce I just want it to be repetitive with the same peak it is fine. But could not do that with my _awesome_ painting skills.. so it is `y = minimum * cos {(6Pie / maximum) * x}`

Comment: @Nope It only works if your function is symmetric around the $x$-axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general form for applying transformations to trig function would be this:
$$
  y = \mathrm{amplitude} \times \cos \left(\frac{2\pi}{\mathrm{period}}x - \mathrm{horizontalShift}\right) + \mathrm{verticalShift}
$$
So in this case we should have something like
$$
  y = -500 \times \cos \left(\frac{2\pi}{(500/3)}x - 0\right) + 0
$$

Comment: Hi Mike so if I have some points that I know for sure they belong to my function, how can I find the equation of my function? Let's say my points are: (-8,0)(-4,-4)(0,0)(4,4)(8,0) and (12,-4). Also, these points are symmetric to each other and to the 0,0. but can I find the equation **any bunch** of points? If no what is your advice? Please if you could guide me through this. I appreciate it

Comment: For these values you have $$y=4*sin(\pi*x/8)$$

Comment: Oh thanks ! But how do I calculate that @cgiovanardi? How could I find it?